# MYSQL ordering data from 1 table using the 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a MYSQL query I can use to order items from a second table.

My example
I'm listing My Stores... each store has a number of products in a diffrent table.
so my store listing displays the number of products in that store..

is there an easy MYSQL query so i can order my stores by number of products

my store doesnt hold a value of the number, it counts the rows in the 2nd table

Comment: Pls post what you've tried, some sample data, and expected output.

Comment: Yes you can, using a `join`. See OMG Ponies' comment.

Comment: well i didnt try anything cause i have a feeling its possible threw mysql. i would of build an array with all my data from the first table... then extratced the data of the products and displayed my array.. but it seem complicated for nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you may want to try something like the following:

```
SELECT     stores.id store_id, COUNT(products.id) num_products
FROM       stores
LEFT JOIN  products ON (stores.id = products.store_id)
GROUP BY   stores.id
ORDER BY   num_products;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE stores (id int, name varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE products (id int, store_id int);

INSERT INTO stores VALUES (1, 'store 1');
INSERT INTO stores VALUES (2, 'store 2');
INSERT INTO stores VALUES (3, 'store 3');
INSERT INTO stores VALUES (4, 'store 4');

INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (3, 1);

INSERT INTO products VALUES (4, 2);

INSERT INTO products VALUES (5, 3);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (6, 3);
```

Result:

```
+----------+--------------+
| store_id | num_products |
+----------+--------------+
|        4 |            0 |
|        2 |            1 |
|        3 |            2 |
|        1 |            3 |
+----------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can also sort in descending order by adding `DESC` after `ORDER BY num_products`:

```
+----------+--------------+
| store_id | num_products |
+----------+--------------+
|        1 |            3 |
|        3 |            2 |
|        2 |            1 |
|        4 |            0 |
+----------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: SELECT *, COUNT(jos_com_ai_prod.idprod) FROM `jos_com_ai_manu` JOIN `jos_com_ai_prod` ON (jos_com_ai_manu.idmanu = jos_com_ai_prod.idmanu) GROUP BY jos_com_ai_manu.idmanu

is my current query but it only returns elements that have products and will not display items without any?

Comment: i thinjk the reason is the ON... is requiring to find a matching product... but if there is no product i want num_product to say 0 and pull the store data

Comment: @StiGMaT: That great. I'm glad it worked. I updated my answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple enough as long as you have something to join to the second table on.

```
Select a.* From `FirstTable` a
Inner Join `SecondTable` b on a.SomeCol = b.SomeCol
Order By b.OrderingCol
```